# Message Box is not showing when submit data to database

Tags: c#, mysql

When I fill signup form and then click submit if data is correct it is successfully added to the database but it didn't show the message "Registration success full"

This is my submit Button

```
private void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string phonetext = Phone_txt.Text;
        string myregex = "[\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d]";  

        Match look = Regex.Match(phonetext, myregex);

        if (UserName_txt.Text != "" && mask1_password_txt.Text != "" &&Email_txt.Text!= "" && Phone_txt.Text != "" && FName_txt.Text != "" && LName_txt.Text != "" &&Address_txt.Text != "")
        {


            if (look.Success && Phone_txt.Text.Length == 10) // if regex success & phone number has 10 digits
            {
                 Classes.Quaries qu = new Classes.Quaries();
                qu.insertIntoSignup(UserName_txt.Text, mask1_password_txt.Text, FName_txt.Text, LName_txt.Text, Address_txt.Text, Phone_txt.Text, Email_txt.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Phone Number");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All Fields Must Be Filled ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

This is the method

```
public void insertIntoSignup(string username, string password, string firstname, string lastname, string address, string phone, string email )
    {
        try
        {

            sql_quary = "Insert Into my_project_data.signup(UserName,Password,FirstName,LastName,Address,Phone,Email) Values('" + username + "','" + password + "','" + firstname + "','" + lastname + "','" + address + "','" + phone + "','" + email + "')";
            string dbuser = "Select UserName From my_project_data.signup where UserName = '" + username + "'";  //check whether username already excistes

            openConnection();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(dbuser, conn);
            datar = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count1 = 0;

            while (datar.Read())
            {
                count1 += 1;
            }
            datar.Close();


            if(count1 == 1)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("UserName Already Exists Please Choose Another UserName");
            }
            else if (count1 == 0)
            {
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql_quary, conn);
                datar = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (datar.Read())
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Registration Sucessfull "); //This message is not showing
                }
                datar.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Something is terribally wrong");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ooooops Error " + ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put Your Messagebox outside while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit muddled mate. You are executing a reader on an Insert statement.

```
 cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql_quary, conn);
 datar = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

where sql_quary is

```
 sql_quary = "Insert Into my_project_data.signup(UserName,Password,FirstName,LastName,Address,Phone,Email) Values('" + username + "','" + password + "','" + firstname + "','" + lastname + "','" + address + "','" + phone + "','" + email + "')";
```

You need to execute the insert statement first typically via

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As it stands you are trying to read the results of an insert statement, which in this case is nothing so

```
while (datar.Read())
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Registration Sucessfull "); 
}
```

never executes.

Id also have this method

```
public void insertIntoSignup(string username, string password, string firstname, string lastname, string address, string phone, string email )
```

return a Result variable to your Ui and execute your messages there. i.e. return an int or even better an enum:

```
public int insertIntoSignup(string username, string password, string firstname, string lastname, string address, string phone, string email )
```

And then depending on that value show one message or the other in the Ui.

Putting your messages in a while loop means if your reader returns more than one result (row), the message will keep popping up, once for every row. Probably not what you want.